# How to properly migrate to Bootstrap5 with same button color and font?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I found the benefits of Bootstrap, but for security reasons I had to upgrade from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5. Now I am having trouble with getting the colors and fonts right for the buttons. This is how it was and what I liked:

[image]

And this is how the same looks with Bootstrap 5:

[image]

The problem is that I find the background color for the Primary button too bright, and for the Light button too weak. Also, the font is a little different, ugly, but not a real problem, but foremost the font size larger, 16px instead of 14px so that the long text does not fit in the (enlarged) button.

This is the complete standalone test source code, tested on Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap 3 - 5 Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- this is bootstrap version 3 : -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

    <!-- this is bootstrap version 5 : -->
    <!--        
        -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        html body buttonXX { /*prevent bootstrap 5 default 16px system-ui -apple-system... font*/
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px !important;
        }

        #custom .btn { /*bigger button for multi line text*/
            width: 133px;
            height: 70px;
            margin: 10px;
            white-space: pre-wrap; /*enables wrapping*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bootstrap 5 Test</h1>
    <div id="standard">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
    </div>
    <div id="custom">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Afvoeren van kratten en emmers</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For simplicity I combined some duplicate scripts. Just remove the XX from the style to enable my quick fix to make the multiline text fit in the button block. And move the comment closing tags to switch between Bootstrap 3 and 5.

NB: I needed the combined `html body button` and `!important` to get the required css specificity

My question:

- Is there a better, more official, and cleaner way to get Bootstrap 5 to behave more like Bootstrap 3?

NB: I am especially looking for a solution that fixes all buttons on various pages with just one central CSS file.

Comment: bootstrap 5 is a whole new framework that has nothing to do with the V3. Also there is no security issue when it comes to CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good points! I am going to look in upgrading to V4 instead

Comment: same thing for V4. V5 and V4 are similar but both are very far from the V3. The whole framework was reworked from 0 since the V4 (to switch from float to flexbox). Better redo the website properly instead of thinking about the migration.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The idea of upgrading came from a "free" security scan on immuniweb.com that flags bootstrap 3.3.7 as bootstrap 3..0.0 with 7 CVE security issues and urgently recommended upgrading to bootstrap 5. However, according to cvedetails.com those issues are totally non-critical, and most versions of bootstrap3 have zero vulnerabilities. Apparently, immuniweb is scaring visitors to sell services . . . no need to "upgrade" bootstrap 3 to 4 or 5. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you'd enter your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.  This would make it easier for other users to find this info